# Cost of living dataset

Tags: data-request, usa, economics, city

I'm trying to compare what the equivalent salary would be between two cities based upon the cost of living in each city.

I want to be able to build something like CNN's cost of living calculator.
http://money.cnn.com/calculator/pf/cost-of-living/

Wolfram Alpha has this available through the [main search engine](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Cost%20of%20living%20index%20boston), but
Wolfram Alpha's API returns data not found for the same query

Has anyone come across a dataset that would allow searching for cost of living based on any city in the U.S.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found an API from [Numbeo](http://www.numbeo.com/common/) ([documentation](http://www.numbeo.com/api/doc.jsp)) that claims

> 8,282,934 prices in 11,072 cities entered by 706,591 users
> (information updated 2022-10-18, [source](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/))

Here is their page related to the [Cost of Living](http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/).

And an [overview of the data for Zurich](http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/city_result.jsp?country=Switzerland&city=Zurich).

Their [Terms of Service](http://www.numbeo.com/common/terms_of_use.jsp) state that the license is [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and [GNU Free Document License](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html) (GFDL).

What I can't find is how to get an API key (or quotas), although I think you can get one once you register as a user.

[image].

Comment: This is a very detailed answer.  I found that applying for an academic api key can be done by sending them an email: http://www.numbeo.com/common/apply_academic_api.jsp.  The only drawback is the data is only for limited cities, but it looks like this might be as close as I'm going to get to what I need.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For the US, this information is generally obtained through the Bureau of Labor (BLS) jointly with the US Census. Data is collected on a regional, state and metropolitan statistical area (MSA). Here are some links:

BLS: http://www.bls.gov/data/#prices

BEA (Bureau of Economic Analysis): http://www.bea.gov/newsreleases/regional/rpp/2014/rpp0414.htm

Answer (score 4):

Here's a link to the [Consumer Price Index on Data.gov](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=CPI&organization=dol-gov&sort=score%20desc%2C%20name%20asc), which has Department of Labor (BLS) and other U.S. Federal agency data set up for download.

Cheers,

Martin

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you want your calculator work for world cities or just the US.

In case it's the first, the National Department of Statistics (Dane) of Colombia posts in a regular basis studies (most likely data with some degree of processing) about prices, with some nice analysis by expenditure groups and the like. You can find them here in Spanish: [link to Dane's report on prices to consumers](http://www.dane.gov.co/index.php/precios-e-inflacion/indice-de-precios-al-consumidor).

I guess each country has some sort of report that is essentially the same.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This API might give you the data you need:

[Cities Cost of Living](https://rapidapi.com/ditno-ditno-default/api/cities-cost-of-living1)

It contains detailed information about the living expenses of 600+ cities around the world, including multiple indexes like Groceries, Purchasing Power and Rent.

On a more detailed level, it has average prices (and ranges) of individual items like a specific food, the cost of an apartment or salary.

And you can get the data in a lot of different currencies.

Comment: Can you expand this answer a bit to include more than just a link?