# Average gasoline price for all countries

Tags: data-request, prices, energy

Where can I find reusable data about the current price of a litre of gasoline (not diesel) in various areas of the world?

Average price, or at least a reasonable approximation, for instance observed prices at a particular gasoline stand.

Must be CC-BY-SA or more permissive.

Answer (score 3):

Try looking at Numbeo. It is a crowd source project on user contributed real-time data. The cost-of-living section has data on gasoline prices.

http://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/

Creative Commons Attribution-Sharealike 3.0 Unported License (CC-BY-SA) and GNU Free Documentation License (GFDL)

Comment: Good job @Andrew. I had posted this data source in another answer but didn't consider it for this question. http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4083/1511

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has the information for all countries:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasoline_and_diesel_usage_and_pricing#Typical_gasoline_prices_around_the_world

Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License

---

There is also http://www.globalpetrolprices.com/gasoline_prices/ but it has a much more restrictive BY-NC-ND license.

Answer (score 2):

The World Bank provides data, but it is aggregated on the yearly level. Their source is German Agency for International Cooperation (GIZ).

**[Pump price for gasoline (US$ per liter)](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/EP.PMP.SGAS.CD/countries)**

> Fuel prices refer to the pump prices of the most widely sold grade of gasoline. Prices have been converted from the local currency to U.S. dollars.

There is a download button for XML, CSV, or Excel.

[World Bank Data License](http://web.worldbank.org/WBSITE/EXTERNAL/0,,contentMDK:22547097~pagePK:50016803~piPK:50016805~theSitePK:13,00.html)

> You are encouraged to use the Datasets to benefit yourself and others in creative ways. You may extract, download, and make copies of the information contained in the Datasets, and you may share that information with third parties. You may also use our application programming interfaces (“APIs”) to facilitate access to the Datasets, whether through a separate Web site or through another type of software application. However, we maintain a list of some specific data within the Datasets that you may not redistribute or reuse without first contacting the original content provider(s), as well as information regarding how to contact the original content provider(s).

([handful](http://web.worldbank.org/WBSITE/EXTERNAL/0,,contentMDK:22547197~pagePK:50016803~piPK:50016805~theSitePK:13,00.html) of datasets have different license)