# Rental Prices in US Cities

Tags: usa

I am conducting a study on different cities, and I am interested in highlighting and comparing rental prices in different US cities. In case you can share some websites (Other than Zillow) where I can these datasets, I would appreciate that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cost of living dataset](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4081/cost-of-living-dataset)

Comment: I don't think it's related, I am looking for retnal prirces while in the link you provided, it doesn't highlight the same.

Answer (score 2):

the US department of housing and urban development has great datasets of rent by area. The dataset contains metro areas so many zipcodes can be mixed.

https://www.huduser.gov/portal/datasets/50per.html

There are other datasets on that website that may be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

This API might give you the data you need:

[Cities Cost of Living](https://rapidapi.com/ditno-ditno-default/api/cities-cost-of-living1)

It contains detailed information about the living expenses of 600+ cities around the world, including multiple indexes like Groceries, Purchasing Power and Rent.

On a more detailed level, it has average prices (and ranges) of individual items like a specific food, the cost of an apartment or salary.

And you can get the data in a lot of different currencies.

Comment: Can you expand this answer a bit to include more than just a link?